# Streaming data to SQL database every 10 minutes with Springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Currently I am trying to improve my skills with Springboot applications and I wanted to know if it is possible for a Springboot application to insert into a MySQL database every 10 minutes (or some quantum of time) while the application is deployed on a server (I am using Elastic Beanstalk), and if so how would I be able to do this and if I would need additional tools to accomplish this.

Comment: You can use the scheduler provided by spring to do something every x minutes.

Comment: so you are saying if I loaded the application on the server, springboot would automatically manage the database without me needing to do anything in the frontend?

Comment: Can u tell me what are u exactly trying to do? Where are u getting the data from which u are inserting in db?

Comment: I am getting it from an API's JSON stream and want to put it in a AWS database that will be used later.

Comment: So are u querying the API JSON every x minutes, and then u would like to insert in AWS database?

Comment: essentially yes

Comment: Ahh okay, then do what is suggested below. Add your database insertion logic in the method annotated with @Scheduled. I hope you are using Spring Data JPA. It will make  things a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@Scheduled` annotation.

Here is a pretty nice [example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks) using cron, fixedRate, and fixedDelay.

Just be mindful that if you are using dynamic schedules (as shown below)

```
@Scheduled("${my.dynamic.schedule}") 
public myScheduledMethod() {
  //do some tasks here
}
```

that you may also introduce logic to ensure all instances are not running at the same time, performing the same task, to avoid redundant behavior.

Comment: I see this is exactly what I am trying to do. Since this is an annotation I assume I just need to add it to the schedule function and spring will handle the rest?

Comment: Yes indeed. Also annotate your Springboot Application class with `@EnableScheduling` and the class containing your scheduler method with `@Component`